# Dragging item to other div with appendTo hidden on source div

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I've two divs: *navpane* and *contentpane*. *navpane* contains a list of items. These items are marked as draggable with the option `appendTo:'#contentpane'`. I've selected `#contentpane` for this option and **not** body due to scroll only inside this pane in case of overflow.

All works fine, but there is one visual drawback. During the dragging operation the dragged items are only visible in the contentpane area and not in the navpane area too.

With `appendTo:'body'` it's OK, but then the scrollbars of the entire browser window appear.

Here is the code snippet:

```
$(".item").draggable({
    helper: 'clone',
    cursor: 'move',
    scroll: true,
    appendTo: '#contentpane'
});
```

Comment: Posting all of the relevant code would really help here. A working example of the problem in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) would also help.

Comment: Ok, here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/QScGQ/

Answer (score 0):

You can set `containment:'document'` on the draggable and use `appendTo:'body'` which should stop the scrollbars appearing. For example:

```
$(".item").draggable({
    helper: 'clone',
    appendTo: 'body',
    cursor: 'move',
    containment:'document'
});
```

The problem is occurring because the absolutely positioned containers are creating new, separate stacking contexts and the draggable is being appended to something with a lower stacking order.

**Edit: Alternative solution - [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/v7a8Y/)**

If you really want to keep the scrollbars on the *contentpane*, the only solution I can think of involves having to change the markup to move the *navpane* inside the *contentpane* so they share the same stacking context. So I've had to sacrifice some semantic structure in order to keep the scrollbars on *contentpane*.The other issue is that the scrollbar will disappear under the *navpane* as I'm using `position:fixed`. I thought that better than seeing the scroll across the entire window bottom.

#### HTML

```
<div id="contentpane">
    <div id="navpane">
      <div class="item">Item A</div>
      <div class="item">Item B</div>
      <div class="item">Item C</div>
      <div class="item">Item D</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.item {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width:200px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

#navpane {
    background-color:lightblue;
    width:250px;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
}

#contentpane {
    background-color:lightgreen;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    overflow-x:auto;
    overflow-y:hidden;
}
```

#### JavaScript

```
$(function () {
  $('.item').draggable({
      helper: 'clone',
      appendTo: '#contentpane',
      cursor: 'move'
  });
});
```

Comment: But i really want the scrollbars. But only for the contentpane.

Comment: I do not think it is possible due to the different stacking contexts that having absolutely positioned containers created. Do the containers need to be `position:absolute`?

Comment: I'll try to use position=relative panels. Thanks for your support.